# TFS Msbuild Precompiling

Tags: tfs, msbuild, precompile

I just need to precompile my asp.net project on build server.
I don't want to use that code. "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler"

I need to precompile my code on build server and I can not create any publish profile because of the main sln has so many projects on it.

How can I precompile an asp.net project on build server with no publish profile.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or new tasks based build? Do you mean you want to use command line to precompile your project without publish profile?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to invoke the [aspnet_compiler tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229863.aspx) to precompile your ASP.NET Web application.

If you use XAML build, you can add the **InvokeProcess activity**(execute the command line) to invoke that compiler to build your project in build process template. If you use the new tasks based build system, you can add a [Command line task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line) to specify the tool.

Comment: Honestly I did it like you said. But when the build runs and completed successfully I can not see any precompiled files in drop location or somewhere. Please look at the above screen shot. thanks.

Comment: I've tested your argument manually with aspnet_compiler tool, and could see the build output in folder "D:\PrecompileDenemeOlgi". Have you checked the folder "D:\PrecompileDenemeOlgi" on your build agent machine?

Comment: Yes I have checked and see nothing in it. :(

Comment: oww damnnn.. I noticed I was looking at the wrong server. D:\PrecompileDenemeOlgi has the precompiled files. :)

Comment: the next step is making rar these files and then sending to target server.